# Setting the height of one div based on another divs height

Tags: jquery

I have two column div layout

```
<div id="site-wrapper">
<div id="leftSidebar">


</div>


<div id="rightSide">

</div>
</div>
```

**my js**

```
 $('#leftSidebar').height($('#rightSide').height());
```

However in IE7 it's adding a chunk of white space at the bottom. Is my jquery correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, outerHeight should do this for you.

http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight says:

> The top and bottom padding and border are always included in the .outerHeight() calculation; if the includeMargin argument is set to true, the margin (top and bottom) is also included.

So if you have margins:

```js
$('#leftSidebar').height($('#rightSide').outerHeight(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some sort of CSS rules for those divs (maybe div's in general) or even `p` or whatever tags you have in there, this should work without a problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/LzHHe/

You could try outerHeight():

`$('#leftSidebar').height($('#rightSide').outerHeight());`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, outerHeight should do this for you.

http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight says:

> The top and bottom padding and border are always included in the .outerHeight() calculation; if the includeMargin argument is set to true, the margin (top and bottom) is also included.

So if you have margins:

```js
$('#leftSidebar').height($('#rightSide').outerHeight(true));
```

where to place it?

Comment: Please use the correct formatting for code and other stuff.