# Set height of container div for carousel based on length of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an img carousel that has the description content on the right for widescreen windows, then when the browser window reaches the breakpoint the description goes below the images. I would like to have the div be sized based on the amount of text in the longest description, otherwise as the carousel animates the rest of the page moves up and down based on the amount of text in the description.

I'm assuming that I need to have some javascript that looks through all the carousel text descriptions and then sets the height of the container div based on the longest description text.

Any ideas how to get this done?

**Update:**
I created this http://jsfiddle.net/chpucat0/ to show what I need. I need all the heights of all the divs to match the div with the most text in it.

```
<div class="description">Small amount of text</div>
<div class="description">Slightly larger amount of text.</p>
<div class="description">And then the really, really, really long description here.</div>
```

Comment: As a best practice here on StackOverflow these types of questions really should have a demo of some kind so were not just giving you free code and the community can learn from the answer, not just copy and paste your answer into their code. http://jsfiddle.net/ is an easy to use and frequently used tool for such demo's. This is why I didn't provide the code as @Phatjam98 did.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to tell me... I appreciate your thoughtful approach. I've updated my post with a simplification of what I need. I'm still really struggling with how to implement the correct code. Can you help me further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar question was asked here in this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614881/dynamically-changing-height-of-div-element-based-on-content?rq=1). And answered as follows "Maybe you could remove the height property (make sure it's not set in the CSS) and let the DIV expand in height by itself." Couple that answer with a query to find which is tallest to detect the desired height, for example... here is another [StackOverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590322/setting-the-height-of-one-div-based-on-another-divs-height) that covers how.

Do you have an example we can view. Please post a link to a demo or paste in your code.

**Update**:
Here is the documentation to an easy to use jQuery function that will allow us to get and manipulate elements' `height`: http://api.jquery.com/height/

**Second Update:** (thank you for adding example code to work with)

Depending on how specific we need to be (i.e., AllElementsHeight must equal ..."the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin." (e.g., based on this requests requirement we can use jQuery's '.outerHeight()' (there are other ways to get this data (such as getting the Javascript 'offsetHeight', I'll omit the performance variation debate as its well documented on the web (i.e., http://jsperf.com/outerheight-vs-offsetheight))))), we can use jQuery to give us the Height of the `div` with the largest `height`, here is the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/) which provides multiple examples.

I've forked the updated post's fiddle and can be viewed here http://jsfiddle.net/id_0t/h6ndwf2x/.

Following is the proof of concept code found in the updated fiddle:

***HTML***

```
<div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ut nisi et tortor aliquet viverra at a nibh. Aenean dictum diam tortor, aliquam posuere nunc elementum sit amet.</div>

<p class="description">Curabitur quis neque ut enim dignissim cursus.</p>

<div class="description">Ut vehicula dolor a mi aliquam feugiat. Integer varius ipsum non nisl vehicula mattis. Curabitur eget eleifend ex. Proin eu quam mi. Sed non mauris dui. Integer tempus at velit id interdum. Fusce sed ultrices nisi. Pellentesque consectetur diam in magna dapibus imperdiet. Pellentesque consectetur diam in magna dapibus imperdiet.</div>

<div>
    This 'div' will not have its height defined because it doesn't have the ".description" class applied to it.
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
div {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.description {
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

***Javascript***

```
var $d = $( ".description" ), 
    tallestDivHeight = 0


$d.each(function (i, v) {
    var $t = $(this), 
        thisDivsHeight = $t.outerHeight()

    console.log(thisDivsHeight)

    if(thisDivsHeight > tallestDivHeight) tallestDivHeight = thisDivsHeight
})


$d.css('height', tallestDivHeight)
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! This was just what I needed. I'm very grateful for your help and thoughtful way of explaining.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are going to have is that the height changes based on how many lines the description is.  That will vary based on the window size, font size, and font family, as well as any variations different browsers use to render the text.

The best way would probably be to loop through your collection, grabbing the height of each description element.  For example:

```
var maxHeight = '';
var heights = [];

$.each(collection, function(item){
  heights.push(item.outerHeight(true));
}

maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);
```

maxHeight should contain the largest number that you can then set all description heights too.

```
$.each(collection, function(item) {
  item.css('height', maxHeight + 'px');
}
```